# Trying to get listview to work

Tags: java, listview, javafx

My question is how do I fix my ListView as it doesn't show anything

So in my main file I have

```
 private ObservableList<Customer> customers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

two customers are added

```
Customer kelly = addCustomer("95432123", "Kelly Lee");
Customer tim = addCustomer("92345678", "Tim Williams");
```

I have a method for returning the ObservableList

```
public final ObservableList<Customer> getCustomers() {
    return customers;
}
```

on my XML file I have a listview linking to the controller via

```
<ListView fx:id="namelistview" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
```

So I am stuck on my controller trying to actually have data printed into the ListView in the form

```
Kelly Lee: 95432123
```

I currently have this in my Controller file but my listview is still showing up as blank

```
public class PizzeriaController extends Controller<Pizzeria> {
ObservableList<Customer> customers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private ListView<Customer> namelistview;

public void namelistview() {
    namelistview.setItems(getPizzeria().getCustomers());
    }



public void initialize() {
}

public final Pizzeria getPizzeria() {
    return model;
}
}
```

Comment: Your observablelist that you should probably use in setitems is customers.  Also, I would setitems in the initialize method. Then maybe do `customers.add(getPizzeria().getCustomers());` in your namelistview method.

Comment: @c0der is right. I should have create an answer, but I was being lazy. Let's hope the answer is not full or errors. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namelistview.setItems method needs an ObservableList as input, so change:

```
namelistview.setItems(getPizzeria().getCustomers());
```

to:

```
namelistview.setItems(customers);
```

and put this code inside the initialize method:

```
public void initialize() {
    namelistview.setItems(customers);
}
```

Now change:

```
public void namelistview() {
     namelistview.setItems(getPizzeria().getCustomers());
}
```

to:

```
public void namelistview() {
     customers.add(getPizzeria().getCustomers());
}
```